# Prove that $(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}$ is divisible by $(a+b+c)^{3}-a^{3}-b^{3}-c^{3}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that 
>   $$(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}$$
>   is divisible by
>   $$(a+b+c)^{3}-a^{3}-b^{3}-c^{3},$$
>   where $a,,b,c -$ integers, such that $(a+b+c)^{3}-a^{3}-b^{3}-c^{3}\not =0$

**My work so far:**

$(a+b+c)^{3}-a^{3}-b^{3}-c^{3}=3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$

Let $333=3\cdot111=3t,$ where $t=111$.

$(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}=(a+b+c)^{3t}-a^{3t}-b^{3t}-c^{3t}$.

***I need help here.***

Comment: $$(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}=?$$ if $a+b=0$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: 0

Comment: So, $a+b$ is a factor of ?

Comment: I do not understand.If $a+b \not =0$?

Comment: $(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3$ has three factors. Show that $(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}$ is divisible by each factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint $1:$**
 Let $f(a)=(a+b+c)^{333}- a^{333} -b^{333} -c^{333}.$

$f(-b)=(-b+b+c)^{333} -(-b)^{333} -b^{333} -c^{333}=0$

So, by Factor theorem we get $(a+b)$ as a factor of the given expression.

Similarly, $(b+c)$ and $(c+a)$ are factors of the given expression.

**Hint $2:$** Now, to prove the divisiblity of the expression by $3$, use Fermat's little theorem.

$a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow a^{333} \equiv a\pmod 3$

Similarly,

$b^{333} \equiv b \pmod 3$
$c^{333} \equiv c \pmod 3$
$(a+b+c)^{333} \equiv (a+b+c)\pmod 3$

So, the given expression is $\equiv 0 \pmod 3$

---

As the given expression is divisible by each of these four factors, it is divisible by $(a+b+c)^3 -a^3-b^3-c^3$.